# A better way to copy a ReadOnlySequence<byte> to a Struct

Tags: c#, marshalling, system.io.pipelines

So I have been working with `System.Buffers` and specifically the `ReadOnlySequence<T>` class lately.

I have a struct of primitives defined with the following:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack =1,CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public partial struct MessageHeader
{
    public MessageVersion Version;
    ...
```

And I can pass this back and forward across the network without any issues and I am leveraging `System.IO.Pipelines` for this.

Converting the `ReadOnlySequence<byte>` back into the struct has caused some head aches.

I started out with this:

```
    private void ExtractMessageHeaderOld(ReadOnlySequence<byte> ros, out MessageHeader messageHeader)
    {
        var x = ros.ToArray<byte>();

        ReadOnlySpan<MessageHeader> mhSpan = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, MessageHeader>(x);

        messageHeader = mhSpan[0];

    }
```

Which created thousands of little byte[] arrays over the life of the server, (which on there own aren't a problem), but with everything else the system is trying to do these put a bit of added pressure on the GC.

So I have moved to using:

```
    private void ExtractMessageHeader(ReadOnlySequence<byte> ros, out MessageHeader messageHeader, ref byte[] workingSpace)
    {
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var rom in ros)
            foreach (var b in rom.Span)
            {
                workingSpace[i] = b;
                i++;
            }

        ReadOnlySpan<MessageHeader> mhSpan = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, MessageHeader>(workingSpace);

        messageHeader = mhSpan[0];
    }
```

This doesn't do any memory allocations, but I just feel like there should be a better way.

The `foreach` loops, and the `MemoryMarshal.Cast()` to a `messageHeader[1]` so I can extract element 0 is a bit of a hack I just happened to stumble upon while reading the source.

I can't find an API to cleanly extract the contents of the `ReadOnlySequence<bytes>` into the `messageHeader`, and while what I have is working, I just feel like one should exist...

**Edit 1:**

I just stumbled across `BuffersExtensions.CopyTo<T>(ReadOnlySequence<T>, Span<T>)` which can replace the foreach loops with.

```
ros.CopyTo(workingSpace);
```

Comment: Does your struct contain only [blittable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types) types? (Note: `string` is not blittable.) I'm assuming so, otherwise you wouldn't have the sequence of bytes in the first place...

Comment: Yes, the entire struct is blittables.  Yes I am using ``Marshal.Copy`` to get a byte[] array on the other end.

Comment: You may be forced to use `byte[]` rather than `ReadOnlySequence<byte>` if you want to absolute maximum performance. Although that's what `System.IO.Pipelines` gives you, so that might not be possible.

Comment: Yes, that's right, the ``ReadOnlySequence<byte>`` comes out of the ``System.IO.Pipeline.PipeReader``, it's the only way that the buffer is provided.  Sure I can copy this to a `byte[]` with the ``foreach`` loops and then do a `Marshal.Copy()` but I was looking for a clean way to do it within the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could reduce the GC pressure somewhat by using `stackalloc` and `Span<byte>` to buffer the data in your first method, like so:

```
public static void ExtractMessageHeaderOld(ReadOnlySequence<byte> ros, out MessageHeader messageHeader)
{
    Span<byte> stackSpan = stackalloc byte[(int)ros.Length];
    ros.CopyTo(stackSpan);

    ReadOnlySpan<MessageHeader> mhSpan = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, MessageHeader>(stackSpan);

    messageHeader = mhSpan[0];
}
```

This may make it faster, but you'd have to instrument it to see if it really helps.

Comment: Thanks. It's negligibly slower, cleaner and most importantly doesn't create any GC pressure.

Comment: If you want to avoid the copy, then use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.sequencereader-1?view=net-7.0